# if statement inside of wordpress post loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I've tried to add an if statement inside of the wordpress loop to not show anything inside of a category, but the posts are still showing up on the front-end, I've got a feeling its something to do with the colon on the end of  as if I change it to a semi colon I get an error (500) but I'm just not sure how to fix it. Does anyone have any idea how to get an if statement into the wordpress post loop?

```
<div class="row page-wrapper">
<?php if ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
    <?php  if ( !in_category('65') ): ?>
        <?php WpvTemplates::left_sidebar() ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(WpvTemplates::get_layout()); ?>>
            <?php
            global $wpv_has_header_sidebars;
            if( $wpv_has_header_sidebars) {
                WpvTemplates::header_sidebars();
            }
            ?>
            <div class="page-content">
                <?php
                rewind_posts();
                get_template_part('loop', 'category');
                ?>
            </div>
        </article>
        <?php WpvTemplates::right_sidebar() ?>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php else: ?>
<article>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;margin-top: 35px;"><?php _e('Sorry, nothing found', 'church-event') ?></h1>
</article>
<?php endif ?>
```

This is the code I've tried to add seen on line 3 and line 20.

I'm just looking to hide all posts from that category from showing on the search page in this case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if I can gain an understanding of what exactly the colon does that would be great too.

Thank you

Comment: @Stuart you forgot ; in 4 & 19 & 23 lines: <?php WpvTemplates::left_sidebar() ?>

Comment: @TDK `in_category()` is a core wordpress function, which just returns a bool. `(bool) True if the current post is in any of the given categories.`

Comment: I don't understand, why you don't have the `while` part of the loop

Comment: Usually, the loop contains `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` and an `endwhile`

Comment: @Stender : thanks sorry

Comment: @Stuart : anycase the colon is correct. if you remove it, the control strucure does not work and error 500 happens
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: @Stender it's just how the theme was in regards the loop (I'll add it though) so it's just down to an inproper use of in_category()?